# Как скомпилировать TypeScript проект

Tags: node.js, typescript, компиляция

Сделал проект, пробую скомпилировать build (`tsc -p run.ts`), выдаёт такую ошибку

> run.ts(1,1): error TS1005: '{' expected.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyEngine",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "svgjs": "2.6.2",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p run.ts",
    "start": "npm run build -- -w"
  }
}
```

**run.ts**

```
import * as SVG from "svgjs";

var draw =  SVG('drawing').size(600, 600);
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).move(100, 50).fill('#f06')
```

При этом выходной js файл всё-таки получается... Использую `WebStorm`.
Вот он

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var SVG = require("svgjs");
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(600, 600);
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).move(100, 50).fill('#f06');
```

Как сделать что бы этот файл можно было исполнить браузером? 
Смущают

```
 exports.__esModule = true;
 var SVG = require("svgjs");
```

Браузер такое не выполняет.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Почему выдаёт при компиляции ошибку и при этом получается результирующий файл?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685